# "Unable to create javax script engine for javascript" extjs

Tags: java, extjs

Following the "default" installation of extjs, I can't get it running with any Java > version 14.

With Java 14 the main warning is:

```
[ERR] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
```

With Java 15 the `ant` build is failing:

```
Exception information:
=======================
/home/ubuntu/my-ext-gen-app/node_modules/@sencha/cmd/dist/plugin.xml:378: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/ubuntu/my-ext-gen-app/build.xml:15: Unable to create javax script engine for javascript
     at com.sencha.ant.AntScript.execute(AntScript.java:121)
     at com.sencha.command.plugin.PluginManager.execute(PluginManager.java:104)
     at com.sencha.command.plugin.PluginManager.executeReverseFirst(PluginManager.java:145)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.BuildEnvironment.execute(BuildEnvironment.java:309)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.AppOrPackageEnvironment.execute(AppOrPackageEnvironment.java:729)
     at com.sencha.command.BasePluginCommands$BasePluginCommand.doExecute(BasePluginCommands.java:125)
     at com.sencha.command.app.AppCommands$BuildCommand.execute(AppCommands.java:470)
     at com.sencha.command.app.AppCommands$WatchCommand.execute(AppCommands.java:909)
     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
     at com.sencha.util.MethodInvoker$Arguments.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:175)
     at com.sencha.cli.Command.dispatch(Command.java:43)
     at com.sencha.command.BasePluginCommands$BasePluginCommand.dispatch(BasePluginCommands.java:289)
     at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:64)
     at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:64)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.dispatch(Sencha.java:80)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.main(Sencha.java:151)
```

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/guides/getting_started/getting_started_with_npm.html

Any way to fix this?

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43067454/ant-running-from-maven-antrun-plugin-cant-find-scripting-engine-on-java-9

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, but with Java 17.

I changed Java to version 8 and I restarted all terminals and it resolved my problem.

Comment: Yes, its a workaround, not quite a solution, we want to move forward not backward.

Comment: I use the same workaround but with Java 11 which is also an LTS release.